# Structural directive - finding the element it is placed on

Tags: angular

With a structural directive, how would I get a hold of the (native) element the directive is on?
With a normal directive, the ElementRef has it's nativeElement pointing to it - eg:

```
<input type="text" example>

@Directive({
  selector: '[example]'
})
export class ExampleDirective {    

  constructor( private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement); // the input
  }
}
```

But with a structural directive, it points to the template comment - eg.

```
<input type="text" *example>

@Directive({
  selector: '[example]'
})
export class ExampleDirective {

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private view: ViewContainerRef,
    private template: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.template);

    console.log(this.el.nativeElement); // template bindings comment
    // how to find the input itself?
  }
}
```

I've tried using various combinations of ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, @ContentChild, @ViewChild - just don't seem to be able to find the input element itself...

Comment: consider this answer in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796556/2145997

Answer (score 13):

All structural directives are added to `<ng-template>` elements. Angular never adds `<ng-template>` elements to the DOM. Therefore it's not possible to get the element a structural directive is added to.

If you use the shorthand syntax with `*` like

```
<div *ngIf="..."></div>
```

angular creates

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="...">
  <div></div>
</ng-template>
```

and because `<ng-template>` is not added, there is no way of getting it and because `<div>` is not the element the structural directive is added to you also can't get this element using the directive reference.

Comment: Thanks Gunter - I was beginning to think this were the case sadly. I know about how angular expands the structural directives into templates, I was just hoping there was still some reference available to the element used - doesn't look that way. Seems an over-site.

I can see the input element (under nextSibling of the TemplateRef) - but nothing in a nice gettable way.

Comment: If you would elaborate a bit what the actual problem is that you try to solve some alternative approaches might be reveal.

Comment: you can do it with queryAllNodes  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796556/2145997
but you directive must be defined in testing module

Comment: @s-f Thanks for the line. It looks this only works for tests though, but not inside application code.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't pretty, but worked for me:

```
this.viewContainer.get(0).rootNodes[0]
```

I used it when implementing a version of `*ngIf` directive but with animation: [animatedIf](https://plnkr.co/edit/mg4z8O4TZW99R0Vs40SM?p=preview).

Comment: It's not ideal but we have a similar situation and because they recently moved the comment to after the node insertion, our old code broke. This works so thank you :) One note: (this.viewContainer.get(0) as any).rootNodes[0] to avoid typing errors

Answer (score 0):

When the structural directive is used on `HTMLElement`, you will not get the reference to that element, as it is not rendered yet. The `input text box` is not rendered yet when you are trying to access it in your code `console.log(this.el.nativeElement); // template bindings comment`

Please refer the link below to know how structural directives in Angular work.
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix

So to get the reference of the element, you can use `attribute directive` on the same element and do the things needed.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [Structural Directives Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#unless) (not sure if it works, but maybe helps you):

```
<input type="text" *example>


@Directive({
  selector: '[example]'
})
export class ExampleDirective {

  constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set example() {
    console.log(this.viewContainer.element.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lenny but I did try this way - hoping it would work but it doesn't - you'll get an undefined for (in your example) this.input - so no nativeElement available.

Comment: @CalvJ sorry my previous answer was just wrong. I **updated** it, not sure if it works, but maybe helps you.

Comment: :-) Thanks again - but that (this.viewContainer.element.nativeElement) will still just grab you the comment! I think perhaps Gunter is correct and there isn't a direct way to get hold of it.