# Is it possible to unit test a structural directive the way we test an attribute directive in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have both attribute and structural directives in my project. I am able to test the attribute directive by creating a test component and using the attribute directive in it's template.

```
@Component({
    template: `<input [myAttrDir]="{prop1: val1, prop2: val2}"/>`
})
export class TestComponent {
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[myAttrDir]'
})
export class MyAttrDirective {
    @Input('myAttrDir') testProp;
}
```

The testing module looks like:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyAttrDirective, TestComponent]
})
```

I get hold of directive this way:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent)
directive = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyAttrDirective))
```

I am able to get the instance of attribute directive.
However when I try this same way to test structural directive, I get null value of directive.
I have checked out official documentation as well and only found the unit testing of attribute directive. The structural directive testing methodology is not given anywhere.

```
@Component({
    template: `<input *myStrucDir="{prop1: val1, prop2: val2}"/>`
})
export class TestComponent {
}
@Directive({
    selector: '[myStrucDir]'
})
export class MyStrucDirective {
    @Input set myStrucDir(data);
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
        private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private el: ElementRef) {

    }
}
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyStrucDirective, TestComponent]
})
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent)
directive = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyStrucDirective))
```

Is it possible to test structural directive in any way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Unit testing is supposed to be about testing *a unit* : you should not have to request  the directives in your component tests.

Comment: It is unit test case file for directive only. I will only change data in test component and see if the directive behaves the way it should. This way is given in the official documentation on angular.io

Comment: You should instead test that in thedirective spec file : you test if the directive does what you expect it to do. In your component, you test if your component behaves the way you expect it to behave.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Looks like you can't query for it. Did you already manage to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I figured out why `debugElement.query(By.directive(MyStrucDirective))` does NOT work for structural directives.

Structural directives are applied to templates (`<ng-template>`) instead of elements. This means, that they are not bound to any `DebugElement`, but rather to a `DebugNode`. That is a small difference, but explains why it is not found.

To find the instance, you have to query differently:

```
# Angular 8.1 or below
debugElement.queryAllNodes(debugNode => debugNode.providerTokens.includes(MyStrucDirective))[0];

# Angular 8.2
debugElement.queryAllNodes(By.directive(MyStrucDirective))[0];
```

Comment: maybe you know how to hang up a spy on the call to createEmbeddedView and clear methods? on ViewContainerRef

Comment: Thank you a lot for that. Worked as a charm. 

I was further investing and could not find the difference between a `DebugElement` vs `DebugNode`