# Structural Directive pass Html Elements attribute value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, directive

I am using Angular CLI 6.1.4 and i am currently struggeling with the following issue:

I created a structural directive which should work similar to `*ngIf` but taking html-element name or id attribute values to decide whether its shown or not.

The problem is that i just cant get my `<button>`'s name attribute passed to my structural directive.

**My Button:**

```html
<button name="bla" *ngIfVisible="this.name">TEST</button> //this is not working!
```

**My structural directive**

```js
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UserPermissionService } from '../services/user-permission.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngIfVisible]'
})
export class NgIfVisible {

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private userPermissionService: UserPermissionService) { }

  @Input()
  set ngIfVisible(name: any) {
      if (this.userPermissionService.isElementVisible(name)) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      }
  }
}
```

I simply want that the name `bla` is passed to the directive...

I already tried:

```html
<button #name="bla" *ngIfVisible="name">TEST</button>
```

and

```html
<button name="bla" *ngIfVisible="$(this).attr('name')">TEST</button>
```

But none of them works... Please Help!

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue

Comment: I hope thats fine so far:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jywjzb

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<button *ngIfVisible="name;name:'bla'">TEST</button>
```

And in your directive, read the extra `name` property as `ngIfVisibleName` (notice how it is `Name` here and not `name`) as an `Input` just like you're doing with `ngIfVisible`.

[How to use Angular structural directive with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789702/how-to-use-angular-structural-directive-with-multiple-inputs)

Comment: this would probably work, but then i am passing a undefined value to my directive property and `bla` to my `@Input`... when the name attribute of the button changes then i have to fix this in name attribute and also in `*ngIfVisible="name;name:'bla'"`. Wouldnt it be better if i could pass the actual `name` attribute of the button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299046/structural-directive-finding-the-element-it-is-placed-on Apparently you can't get a handle on the element if you are using a structural directive.